# why is it whenever I open my solution file it always creates a new subfolder?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am using visual sourcesafe 8.0 and there is a weird behavior that is extremely puzzling to me. We have this brand new project, the first time I got it from vss, everything was fine. But after I reset the working directory and got the source code, whenever I open the project by double-clicking the sln file, it always creates a subfolder under the current folder, and pull the source code from vss again. Furthermore, if I double-click the sln file under the subfolder, it will create another subfolder under that subfolder and pull the source code again. I think it must be a mapping issue or the sln file is not correct. Anyone know how to fix it? BTW, my project is a web site project (with a solution file)

Answer (score 0):

You can go to Visual Studio menu File->Source Control->Change Source Control and check/update the mapping there.

Comment: Check/update is not an option... You can click Browse... button in the Change Source Control dialog to check and update the server mapping.